# How do you get texta ink (permanent marker) off your hands?

Tags: cleaning

I tried hand soap, but it didn’t work. I also tried hand sanitizer; same thing didn’t work. Hair spray didn’t really work either. My hands are now all pinkish red and it’s sorta staining the walls and carpets when I touch them.

Answer (score 1):

Try following steps:

1. Get your hands greasy in a fatty substance like hand cream. Oil or fat suitable for eating will do, as will baby oil.
2. Wipe it off with paper or an old rag you will throw away. Instead of just wiping you can also scrape it off with something straight but not sharp.
3. Re-apply and wipe till no colour comes off when wiping.
4. Now re-apply and wash your hands, first with normal soap.
5. Then, if needed, with 'garage' soap. That is soap which is strong and has sand or some other gritty bits in it.

At the end of all cleaning, make sure you have your hands protected with cream and leave that to soak in for a while.

Comment: Thx for the advice

Comment: Baby oil is mild on your skin and works pretty well, too.

Comment: @Stan, that is a good one and being for babies it will be safe to use. (Mineral oils might do the work, they are not health safe.)

Answer (score 0):

Rub it with a bit of WD-40 then wash with soap and water

Answer (score -2):

try Washing your hands with kerosene

Comment: Hi! Welcome to [lifehacks.se]. Please add why and/or how this answer is helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Lifehacks! Do you have any resources explaining why this works, or how somebody can do this (safely!)? Thanks!